# Getting classnames for elm from a javascript object

Tags: javascript, css, elm

We have a team of developers who create standard css-classes with tailwind.css which is generally used for Vue/React components. However, we are trying to use elm for a new project and would like to use the same classes from a js-file, as they are being maintained.

How should one import from javascript-file:

```
export const card = {
  cardSelected: 'bg-blue-50',
  cardOutline: 'f-card-outline absolute rounded-8 inset-0 transition-all border-2',

};

export const toaster = {
  toasterContainer: 'fixed fixed-ios-fix bottom-16 left-0 right-0 mx-8',
  toaster: 'f-toaster grid f-grid auto-rows-auto',
};
```

Such that those styles gets set on an element. E.g with toaster:

```
div [class 'f-toaster grid f-grid auto-rows-auto'][]
```

Comment: What do you exactly want and how far did you try?

Comment: What I want: To be able to use the classes specified in the js-file in my elm code, as they get maintained.
How far did I try: Im trying to send the objects in via flags/ports and Decode them with Json.Decode.Value and set the result string as class.

Comment: Please share your tryings. This is still not clear to me.

Comment: We are currently trying the above. I'll come back to you after we've either failed or succeeded :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with [`flags`](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/flags.html).

On your js file you could have:

```
const app = Elm.Main.init({
    node: document.getElementById('main'),
    flags: {
        card: {
            cardSelected: 'bg-blue-50',
            cardOutline: 'f-card-outline absolute rounded-8 inset-0 transition-all border-2',
        }
    }
})
```

and your `Main.elm` would look something like this:

```
type alias CardValues =
    { cardSelected : String
    , cardOutline : String
    }


type alias Card =
    { card : CardValues }


type alias Model =
    { flags : Card }


main : Program Card Model Msg
main =
    Browser.element
        { init = \flags -> ( { flags = flags }, Cmd.none )
        , view =
            \model ->
                Html.div
                    [ Html.class model.flags.card.cardOutline ]
                    [ Html.h1 [] [ Html.text "Here!" ] ]
        , update = \_ model -> ( model, Cmd.none )
        , subscriptions = \_ -> Sub.none
        }
```

Comment: Fantastic answer! It worked like a charm. Thank you for helping a beginner like myself!